# Displaying data from databases - including images

Tags: php, mysql, image

This is my webpage:

http://www.autoweek62.uni.cc/carprice.php

Here is the source code for it:

```
<?php 

    $dbname = "autoweek_auto1"; 
    $loginname = "autoweek_root"; 
    $loginpass = "PASSWORD (not my real one)"; 
    $dbhost = "localhost"; 

    echo('<html><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">'); 
    echo('<font face="arial" size="+4"><center>'); 
    echo("Database $dbname"); 

    $id_link = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $loginname, $loginpass); 

    $tables = mysql_list_tables($dbname, $id_link); 

    $num_tables = mysql_num_rows($tables); 

    // store table names in an array 
    $arr_tablenames[] = ''; 

    // store number of fields per table(index 0,1,2..) in an array 
    $arr_num_fields[] = ''; 
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_tables; $i++) { 
        $arr_tablenames[$i] = mysql_tablename($tables, $i); 
        $arr_num_fields[$i] = mysql_num_fields(mysql_db_query($dbname, "select * from $arr_tablenames[$i]", $id_link)); 
    } 

    // store field names in a multidimensional array: 
    // [i] == table number, [ii] == field number for that table 
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_tables; $i++) { 
        for ($ii=0; $ii < $arr_num_fields[$i]; $ii++) { 
            $result = mysql_db_query($dbname, "select * from $arr_tablenames[$i]", $id_link); 
            $hash_field_names[$i][$ii] = mysql_field_name($result, $ii); 
        }      
    } 

    for ($i=0; $i < $num_tables; $i++) { 
        echo("<center><h2>Table $arr_tablenames[$i] </h2></center>"); 
        echo('<table align="center" border="1"><tr>'); 
        $result = mysql_db_query($dbname, "select * from $arr_tablenames[$i]", $id_link); 
        for ($ii=0; $ii < $arr_num_fields[$i]; $ii++) { 
            echo("<th>"); 
            echo $hash_field_names[$i][$ii]; 
            echo("</th>"); 
        } 
        echo("</tr><tr>"); 
        $number_of_rows = @mysql_num_rows($result); 
        for ($iii = 0; $iii < $number_of_rows; $iii++) { 
            $record = @mysql_fetch_row($result); 
            for ($ii=0; $ii < $arr_num_fields[$i]; $ii++) { 
                echo("<td>"); 
                echo $record[$ii]; 
                echo("</td>"); 
            } 
        echo("</tr>"); 
        } 
        echo("</table>"); 
    } 



    echo('</body></html>'); 
?>
```

It displays, but I'm not sure how to get it to display in a manner similar to this:

redbook.com.au/new-cars/results.aspx?Ns=p_Make_String|0||p_ClassificationType_String|0||p_Family_String|0||p_Year_String|1||p_SequenceNum_Int32|0&N=2994+2951+4294961316+4294843565&TabId=1407343

[not linked since I can't post more than 1 being new here]

(although mine is simply the make, model, bodystyle and prices as a list, not as complicated as the link above!)

I've Googled for some inspiration, but despite trying haven't got any far. I'm not looking for an instant answer, but any solutions are welcomed!

Displaying images is the trickiest part... I have the JPGs stored on the server, trying to get them to display is a problem.

All help is welcomed!

Comment: looks like you are doing wrong everything. muisuse a database, a table and a picture

Comment: Can you give an example of what is stored in the image table of your database? It might be just me, but I'm not sure I understand how you store your images.

Comment: He has the images stored in a database (as blobs). You can do it like that if you want, but it's a lot of work to replicate the facilities a web server offers when it comes to retrieving them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a separate script that returns just the image.

In that script you retrieve the image from the database, output mime-type header and then the raw image data. In your main HTML outputting script you just write `<img src="getImage.php?id=1234" />`